# Show All Countries in Drop down menu

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-core

I am registering Cities and for that I want a drop down menu of Countries. The data comes correctly on controller but after that it show errors.

Here is my code 'Model View'

```
public class CountryCityViewModel
{
  public int CountryId { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
  public string CountryListId{ get; set; }
}
```

'CityController'

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  var result = await _countryService.GetAllCountriesCity();
  ViewBag.Cities = result;
  return View(result);
}
```

'HTML'

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, "Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 @Html.DropDownList(, new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities, "CountryId", "Name"))
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

'City Service Class'

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CountryCityViewModel>> GetAllCountriesCity()
{
  var uri = $"{_siteConfiguration.ApiBaseUrl}{ApiEndPoint.Get_Countries_All}";        
  var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
  var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<CountryCityViewModel>>(contents);
  return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Comment: So... Where is the exception message?

Answer (score -1):

YourPage.cshtml

```
@{
    var list = _countryService.GetAllCountriesCity().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
               {
                   Value = x.CountryId.ToString(),
                   Text = x.Name
               }).ToList();
}
<select asp-items="@list" asp-for="CountryId" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: 1. The question doesn't state the problem they have encountered with their existing code (other than a vague mention of "errors"). Answering low quality questions degrades the quality of the website. Worse still, we have no means of determining if your answer is correct without knowing the problem. 2. This answer doesn't explain what's wrong with the current solution, or how your new code solves that.

Comment: Seems you didn't read my comment. Since you clearly have more detailed knowledge of OP's problem, can you tell me what errors OP refers to with _"but after that it show errors."_? Why are those errors caused by OP's current code? How does your code fix them?